# Como fazer uma chave primária composta por duas chaves estrangeiras diretamente no EntityFramework?

Tags: chave-composta

Ja vi várias explicações, e sei do que se trata, mas só vi a sintaxe nos scripts e não diretamente nas classes. Quando tento fazer a migration, não é aceito porque não tem uma chave primária explícita. Como "explicar" isso.
meu código abaixo:

```
    [ForeignKey("Pedido"), Column(Order= 0)]
    public int IdPedido { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Produto"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int IdProduto { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Quantidade")]
    public float Qtd { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Preço de Venda")]
    public float PrecoVenda { get; set; }
```

Comment: Tenta incluir o atributo `[Key]` nas duas propriedades, você só definiu a chave estrangeira e está tentando subir a tabela sem a chave primária

Comment: Deu certo! obrigado!